# CentOs 7 - MobaXterm - X11 Forwarding per user

Tags: centos, ssh, permissions, x11

I am using [MobaXTerm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) to connect to my **CentOs 7** Server.

I have set  `X11Forwarding yes` in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. The root user is able to start the X11-Gui for example `gedit`.

The other users can not issue `gedit` and see the X11-gui.

**Do the other users need permissions?**

**If so *which*, *where* and *how*?**

Answer (score 2):

timeout in locking authority file `/home/username/.Xauthority`
When logging on a machine with `ssh` (e.g. from lxplus to your desktop PC) with X11 forwarding, you get an error:

`/usr/bin/xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/username/.Xauthority`.

This happens because of `selinux`. You need to check the status of `selinux`.

```
sestatus
```

should give you in the case of the presence of the error something like

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

As you see the current status is enforcing, and that's what is causing the problem. You need to become root with `su` then run

```
setenforce 0
```

and this should then make the output of `sestatus` look like

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Now you should be able to log on the machine using `ssh`.